# Python: how to stack multiple array together along a new axis

Tags: python, matrix

I have three matrices, R, B, G, which all are the same in size, say m*n. I want to stack all three of them together into a different channel of a new matrix (3*m* n or m*n*3), as implemented in Matlab:

```
 A(:,:,1) = R
 A(:,:,2) = G
 A(:,:,3) = B
```

How do I achieve this efficiently in Python?

Comment: Are you using a particular package (e.g. NumPy) for your matrices, or are they just pure lists?

Comment: @Alden: yeah. I know numpy has stack functions, but they seem only to be applicable to two matrices

Answer (score 4):

[numpy.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) should work for three arrays:

```
numpy.stack((R, G, B))
```

For example,

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[2,1]])
b = numpy.array([[3,3],[4,4]])
c = numpy.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
print(numpy.stack((a, b, c)))
```

prints

```
[[[1 2]
  [2 1]]

 [[3 3]
  [4 4]]

 [[5 6]
  [7 8]]]
```

Comment: TypeError: stack() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Make sure you are passing `(R, G, B)` (one argument, a tuple containing the three arrays), not `R, G, B` (the three arrays as individual arguments).